# Website working on any web browser size HTML

Tags: html, css, resize

The issue:
I'm working simple html website that I want to work on any web browser size, so basically if you resize the browser the website will resize to and you won't have to scroll horizontally on the webpage.

I am assuming this has to do with CSS, I've been going thru my html book but unfortunately it doesn't cover this, I've also tried googling but I don't really now how to put it in words so basically google doesn't help me, at least not until I know what this is called.

Comment: Look for [***responsive web design***](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+web+design) (a good article at http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for I guess would be **responsive** design / css.

If you are ok with reusing existing frameworks I'd suggest you try:

- [lessframworkd](http://lessframework.com/)
- [responsive grid system](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/)
- [gskeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) *
- [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) *

*** are fullblown frameworks that include a lot of other features as well

Or have a look at this [nice collection](http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for these words:

CSS GRID SYSTEM » http://960.gs/
ADAPTIVE CSS DESIGN
FLUID CSS DESIGN
or even
MEDIA QUERY CSS